# Display brand name for a product in Solidus (Spree)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

I created the taxonomy "Brand" and now I would like to add the brand name of a specific product. How can I do that?

```
<% if products.any? %>
  <div id="products" class="inline product-listing row" data-hook>
    <% products.each do |product| %>
    ... Insert here the brand of the product 
    <% end %>
    <% reset_cycle("classes") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements of a Taxonomy is called a taxon. If there is only one taxonomy, you can display them like this for instance :

```
<%= product.taxons.map(&:name).join(',') %>
```

Or if you specify the element `taxonomy_categories_name` with your taxonomy name in the yaml locale file `en.yml` :

```
...
taxonomy_brands_name: "Brand"
...
```

you can call the brand simply like this :

```
<%= product.brand %>
```